# Excel 2010: Create a column chart that groups items and then charts them by year

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am having no end of angst trying to build what I thought would be a simple column chart. My data are in three columns: Player in Column "A", Year (from 2005-17) in "B", Points for each year in "C". I am trying to get a column chart that has the points scaled on the "Y" and players along the "X", player-by-player (that is, first all of Smith's points, with columns above year-by-year, then all of Jones', etc.). I want the columns above each player to be the points earned in the individual years. The maddening thing is that I'm sure I figured out how to do this many years ago, but I'll be flupped if I can figure it out again now.

Here's how the data look in the worksheet:

[image: Worksheet data example]

I'll keep searching the SU site for similar questions, and in the meantime thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel 2010 handy, but here's one way to do it in Excel 2016. I *think* you should be able to do the same in 2010.

1. Get your data into a form with one points column per player
2. Next, display it as a 2D Column Chart, using the first type -- Clustered Column
3. The chart as-is will be Year along the X axis, with the bar clusters being one per player. But if you then "Switch Row/Column Data" (in 2016-speak), you'll get the format you describe, with Player along the X, and then the bar clusters being one per year. (There's probably a way to get the Row/Column correct, right of the Insert, but I can't see how. Transposing the Row and Column aspect of the table doesn't do it.)
4. Prettify as needed

I've attached an example.**

[image: Example solution.]

I've also shown what could be done in Excel 2016 in terms of naming the individual bars, in addition to each group being named per Player. That involves enabling a data label for each series, making that label be the Series name (not the value of the specific point), and then a bit of formatting jiggery pokery. I'd like the space between each player's group to be wider than it is -- at least twice a bar width -- but I can't remember how to do that.)

---

** It's obviously not important, but for speed I filled the points column using RANDBETWEEN(50,150). That's why the values don't match yours.